# erb breaks strings on spaces?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<li class=<%= @page_name == "home" ? "active span2" : "span2" %>>
```

turns into:

```
<li class="active" span2>
```

When the statement evaluates true.

My expected result is:

```
<li class="active span2">
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quotes within your tags are essentially declaring the contents within as `String` objects. The output of the statement is a string, but the string will not be encapsulated in quotes. The value of the class attribute *must* be in quotes in order for the markup to be valid. Subsequently, you'll need to enclose the entire statement within double quotes:

```
<li class="<%= @page_name == 'home' ? 'active span2' : 'span2' %>">
```

Comment: Oh, right! And thanks for alternating your quotes, good catch.

Answer (score 3):

The output of your statement is actually

```
<li class=active span2>
```

which will be turned to your output by most browsers, in an effort to correct invalid markup.

You'll want to have it render this way:

```
<li class="<%= @page_name == "home" ? "active span2" : "span2" %>">
```

Comment: I wish I could accept 2 answers as yours is very simply laid out.